# Modification of RSS feed is not consistent

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, rss

I am using the following code in my child theme's functions.php file to replace the_author() value (dc:creator node) with the value of an Advanced Custom Fields text field named custom_byline. It seemed to be working like a charm, but there are some posts which inexplicably don't update ... do you see issues with the code I didn't catch?

```
    if(is_feed()) {  
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        if (get_field('custom_byline') != '') {
          $creator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_byline', true);
        }
    }  
    return $creator;  
}  
add_filter('the_author','custom_byline_in_feed');
```

Comment: First of all I would use the same function to check the value and use the value so I would use `if(get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_byline', true)!= ''){$creator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_byline', true);}`. After that what do you mean "but there are some posts which inexplicably don't update" ? when updating post you don't get the custom field updated or you don't see what you expect in the feed ? Also please post the full code of your  function

Comment: I'll make the consistency switch you recommend - for cleanliness sake - but it works either / both ways. 

There are posts in the feed which have custom_byline value but the feed dc:creator is not changed.

What I've found since my original post was that some of the custom_byline values contain apostrophes (ex: O'Reilly) and that's causing the issue.

Comment: try to use `str_replace("'","&apos;",get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_byline', true));`

Comment: No dice. I was in the midst of trying that when you commented. No change.

Comment: try to var_dump the custom field and see what's in there

Comment: It returns the original dc:creator value ... i.e. the_author()

Comment: I guess there can be a little mess with the get_the_ID() function, it would be interesting to see the first part of your function, double check if the $post_id changes for each element of the array you're fetching

Comment: The ID's seem fine - I'm checking to see the difference between the_title_rss and the_title to see what they're doing to fix this in other content before it hits the feed

Comment: 212 // RSS filters
213 add_filter( 'the_title_rss', 'strip_tags' );
214 add_filter( 'the_title_rss', 'ent2ncr', 8 );
215 add_filter( 'the_title_rss', 'esc_html' );

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L0

Comment: I dunno what’s up but it’s working. I wonder if I was banging my head on a caching issue and just being impatient. I’ll give it a day and review.